# convertir query a CakePHP 3.5

Tags: sql, cakephp

Necesito calcular el ranking de usuarios que tiene un puntaje. Para esto encontre en otro hilo la siguiente query que necesitaria traducir al formato cakephp 3.0 o 3.5:

```
SELECT *, FIND_IN_SET(points,  
 (SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT points ORDER BY points  DESC) 
  FROM    view_ent_users)) as rank
  FROM   view_ent_users
  WHERE nickname = 'Sebass'
  ORDER BY points DESC
```

Me podrian ayudar a traducirla?

Gracias, saludos.

Comment: Traduce tu pregunta estad en **SO En Español**

Comment: no, no se como pasarlo a cakephp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voy a suponer que tu entidad se llama *Users* y que nos encontramos en *UsersController*, puedes lograrlo con el [Query Builder](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#selecting-data) de CakePHP de esta manera:

```
$result = $this->Users
    ->find()
    // Seleccionamos el campo rank
    ->select(['rank' => 'FIND_IN_SET((points), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT points ORDER BY points DESC) FROM view_ent_users))'])
    // Selecionamos todos los campos de la tabla
    ->select($this->Users)
    ->where(['nickname' => 'Sebass'])
    ->order(['points' => 'DESC']);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por el codigo. Pero retorna el siguiente error: "syntax error, Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function FIND_IN_SET"

Comment: Lo acabo de probar utilizando CakePHP 3.5.12 con PHP 7.2.4 y MySQL 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21 y funciona. Si haces un `$this->Table->find()` te regresa resultados?

Comment: Si, regresa resultados si ejecuto $this->_table->find();

Comment: ¿Y si ejecutas directamente la query en tu manejador de base de datos te regresa el resultado esperado?

Comment: Si, la query funciona ok. La he ejecutado directamente y retorna el resultado que quiero obtener por cake. Algo no le gusta del FIND_IN_SET.

Comment: Así parece, lo extraño es que si me funciona, me puedes decir las versiones de tu mysql y cakephp?

Comment: Si cambio points por "un valor" no da error: ->select(['rank' => 'FIND_IN_SET("65", (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT points ORDER BY points DESC) FROM view_ent_users))'])  Pero para todos los registros pone el mismo rank.

Comment: Si puedes poner un ejemplo de los campos de la BD para poder reproducirlo?

Comment: id | name | points

Comment: points tiene 4 registros con valores 65, 65, 115 y 10

Comment: El problema es que por alguna razon si no informo en el primer parametro del FIND_IN_SET un valor entre " " dar el error. No me permite poner el campo points

Comment: ya encontre el error. hay que poner e primer parametro del FIND_IN_SET entre ( ) y funciona: ->select(['rank' => 'FIND_IN_SET((points), (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT points ORDER BY points DESC) FROM view_ent_users))'])  Gracias por tu ayuda!!!